# Rails 3.1 Assets, Cache-Control, Max-Age and Expires headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, asset-pipeline, amazon-cloudfront

I currently have an app on Heroku Cedar stack running with Unicorn.

I also have CloudFront configured as a custom origin to host my css/js assets.  However it seems like no matter which way I configure the static/assets for Rails it will not allow me to set the Cache-Control, Max-Age or Expires headers.

This is important as the headers are pass-through with CloudFront and if I can't set them CloudFront won't cache them properly.

Comment: If this answers the question you can mark it accepted by selecting the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding this to your environments/production.rb file.

```
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"
```